# How do I exclude form unsubscribes in a dynamic list

Tags: hubspot

We collect the registrations of events via a form in a dynamic list. How can we remove people who have unsubscribed via email or telephone from this list, since you cannot delete form submissions? Help? ‌‌

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an active list, you can exclude unsubscribed contacts by adding a filter for "Unsubscribed from all email is not equal to True":

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot attached]